# How to get reference of the parent recyclerview from its child recyclerview views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I've got a situation here. I have a recyclerview. The children of the recyclerview comprise of a TextView(Serial Number) and another recyclerview. The children of the second recyclerview comprise of an EditText(descriptions).

I need to create a structure like this `Map<SerialNumber(String), List<description(String)>>`. To do this I think I need to get the reference of the SerialNumber from the inner Adapter.

I am getting no clue to do this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just use OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType), parent Parmeter.

```
      public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
               ImageView productImage = parent.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.product_image);
            }
```